# How to create checked/unchecked custom exceptions in Java?

Tags: java

When I create my own exceptions, is it possible to mark them as being checked/unchecked? (using some annotation, maybe?) Or, is extending Exception/RuntimeException the only way of doing it?

Thanks.

Comment: What would you suggest as an alternative?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

The only way of doing it is to extend Exception (or a subclass thereof) for a checked exception, and extending RuntimeException (or a subclass thereof) for an unchecked exception.

Given how lightweight it is to do that, and the benefits you get from extending those classes, I don't think that's too onerous.

Answer (score 17):

Checked Exception

By extending `Exception`, you can create a checked exception:

```
class NotEnoughBalance extends Exception {
     // Implementation
}
```

Unchecked Exception

By extending `RuntimeException`, you can create unchecked exception:

```
class NotEnoughBalance extends RuntimeException {
     // Implementation
}
```

Comment: This is not correct. You don't need to extend `IOException` to create a checked  exception. _Every_ exception in Java is a checked exception _unless_ it extends `RuntimeException`.